# Error building OpenCV for Android arm64-v8a

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, cmake, arm64

I am trying to build OpenCV 3.2 for android. When I tried to build it for the armeabi-v7a configuration I had no problems compiling it. However, when I tried to compile it for the arm64-v8a hardware I am getting the following message:

```
/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:87:12: error: expected ')'
    void (*sa_sigaction)(int, struct siginfo*, void*);
           ^
/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/signal.h:102:24: note: expanded from macro 'sa_sigaction'
#define sa_sigaction _u._sa_sigaction
                       ^
/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:87:10: note: to match this '('
    void (*sa_sigaction)(int, struct siginfo*, void*);
         ^
/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:87:12: error: duplicate member '_u'
    void (*sa_sigaction)(int, struct siginfo*, void*);
           ^
/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/signal.h:102:22: note: expanded from macro 'sa_sigaction'
#define sa_sigaction _u._sa_sigaction
                     ^
/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:86:18: note: previous declaration is here
    sighandler_t sa_handler;
                 ^
/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/signal.h:101:20: note: expanded from macro 'sa_handler'
#define sa_handler _u._sa_handler
```

This is how cmake is configured:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN -DANDROID_NDK=$NDK_ROOT  -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a  -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=21  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/opencv/arm64 -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=false -DTIFF_LIBRARY=$TIFF_LIBRARY -DTIFF_INCLUDE_DIR=$TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR -DBUILD_OPENEXR=false
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I have been struggling with it for two days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: I noticed that cmake ouputs this line:

```
Target:                      Android 21 armv7-a
```

even though I set the abi to arm64-v8a. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line). A little bit difficult in the beginning to set up, but once it's done it's basically regular `c++` coding **without Java UI**.

Comment: All those paths are the arm32 headers, not the arm64 ones. Something is going wrong with your build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have solved this problem.
I also met this issue when I use cmake-gui first, and then assign a toolchain file.
I solved this problem, just use

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK_PATH/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a"
```

and then use cmake-gui to set build subsystem. everything will be fine then.